# Letting the user edit a single text line in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

In my Node.js application I want to display text lines to user and the user should be able to accept the line or edit it. I have looked for a npm module implementing a simple text editor in text terminal but with no luck. Does anyone know such a module? Or should I save the text line to a file and then spawn an external text editor for editing? It sounds like overkill for my situation. My app would be run in Windows.

Comment: Maybe [commander](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/).prompt() or .confirm() is what you're looking for?

Comment: Those methods seem to be for asking user input but what I need is the ability to move cursor around and edit the given text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in [readline](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input : process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.write(YOUR_LINE_HERE);
rl.question('> ', function(answer) {
  console.log('User entered: ', answer);
});
```